# how to migrate on premise SQL Azure database to Microsoft Acess

Tags: azure-sql-database

Is it possible to migrate on premise Sql azure database to Microsoft Access ? If yes can someone guide me on that . Thanks for your suggestion .

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by on premise SQL Azure? Do you have a SQL Azure database that you would want to get on premise and then convert to access? If so you can back up with Redgates SQL Azure backup - http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-azure-backup/discontinued to an on premise SQL Server and then migrate the data to access.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SSMA. Here's a Step by Step guide that I had written few months ago to migrate Access to SQL Azure, if that's what you meant: http://blogs.solidq.com/pdoshi/post.aspx?id=9&title=migrating+microsoft+access+database+to+sql+azure+using+sql+server+migration+assistant++%28ssma%29